# c# returning class implementation in lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

With the example that I have :

```
public class A
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to Return List of Class A to Class B by lambda, without using any class extensions? Im curious whether the current framework able to do this or not.

```
public void Something()
{
    List<A> objA = new List<A>();
    List<B> objB = new List<B>();
    objB = objA.Where(x => x.ID == "").ToList();
}
```

Supposedly, Class B is an implementation of Class A. Why would this code would return error

> Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Collection.Generic.List A>' to
>   System.Collection.Generic.List B>

Comment: You are missing a cast: `objA.Where(x => x.ID == "").Cast<B>().ToList()` - or more safely: `objA.Where(x => x.ID == "").OfType<B>().ToList()`

Comment: @KlausGütter Hi, I have never used Cast before. is it a bad practice to use it? if you mind to explain a little bit about it, I will accept your answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objA may contain objects of class A or B, so you cannot directly assign the result of your query to objB.

If you are sure that every object passing the `Where` is in fact an object of class B, you can write:

```
objB = objA.Where(x => x.ID == "").Cast<B>().ToList();
```

This casts every object pasing the Where to B, so you get an `IEnumerable<B>` which turns to a `List<B>` by the `ToList` call.

If also objects of type A may pass the Where, using OfType instead of Cast uses only those objects which are of type B:

```
objB = objA.Where(x => x.ID == "").OfType<B>().ToList();
```